# Delete row from table with conditions uniqueField = 1

Tags: mysql, sql

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE uniqueField = 1
```

When MySQL finds the row with `uniqueField = 1`, it will delete it. Then does it stop checking other rows, because a unique field only has one row with the value `1`?

Or will MySQL continue to search even after it finds a row with `uniqueField = 1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `uniqueField` is declared `UNIQUE`, an implicit index is created to police the unique constraint.

`MySQL` will most probably use this index to locate the record to delete.

Since this index will be `UNIQUE`, the engine will only scan one record.

If the field is not declared unique and not indexed, then `MySQL` will have to scan all records to check the value of this field.

Answer (score 3):

The action depends on the presence of an index, and the type of index.

If uniqueField is part of a `UNIQUE` index, MySQL will use the index to locate the matching row, which can be at most one row, and delete it.

If uniqueField is part of a `INDEX` non-unique index, it will use the index to locate the matching rows, which can be 0, 1 or more, and delete them.

If uniqueField is not part of any index, it will need to scan the entire table, front to back. Even if it finds one row, it will continue to scan the table until the end.

MySQL supports an extension to `DELETE` with `LIMIT` clauses: `DELETE FROM sometable WHERE uniqueField = 1 LIMIT 1` and it can use this to optimize the query. It will stop after the first deletion, and not scan until the end. This does not replicate, as the order of rows on the master and the slave is not necessarily identical (i.e. it has the potential to delete different rows on the master and the slave, leading to data divergence.)

You can use `DELETE` with `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY` to make this again replication safe, at the added cost of sorting: `DELETE FROM sometable WHERE uniqueField = 1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1`.

Or you can `SELECT id FROM sometable WHERE uniqueField = 1` first, and then build an id list and `DELETE FROM sometable WHERE id IN ( ...)`, which is also replication-safe.

Comment: The `SELECT` and `DELETE` in your last suggestion should be combinable into one query...

Comment: Yes, they should. Only that the MySQL optimizer treats DELETE ... WHERE f IN ( SELECT ... ) differently that DELETE ... WHERE f IN ( const, const, const, ...). Don't get me started. And don't use subqueries in WHERE ... IN ( ... ) clauses before upgrading to MariaDB 5.3, where this is finally fixed.

Comment: I guess using an `EXISTS` instead would sorta defeat the purpose, wouldn't it ^^

Comment: Same thing. MySQL and Subqueries -> MariaDB 5.3 as soon as it becomes available.